# How to add multiple scrollable views dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to achieve this design shown below. All I can think of is having a `LinearLayout` as parent layout with `android:orientation="vertical"` and add listViews with horizontal scroll dynamically inside the linear layout, but it seems very inefficient solution.

What can be the best possible approach to achieve this UI? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest trying the nested recycler view :- https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/nested-recyclerview-in-android-e5afb2b9771a it will  help you manage dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will create a RecyclerView witch adds the rows of the Textview and another recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The second recyclerview will contains columns of those cards. Of course the second recyclerview will contain the LinearLayoutManager like that:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

I'm not sure if that solution will be the most efficient one. I would like to read more comments to find a better solution, if it exists.